# What type of project should I use for integration tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mvvm, integration-testing

Simple question, but I have been unable to find an answer.  Using Visual Studio 2012, on a WPF project using MVVM model, should integrations test be a console app, or built into a Test library.  Should I be using regular classes, or Basic Unit Test classes.

## Update

I have already completed my Unit Tests and they are all passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal test project.

Integration tests are normal tests that actually hit external resources. They make sure that your code functions properly when presented with actual data/resources (external, internal, whatever). Unit tests on the other hand generally deal with Mocks/in-memory resources. They are basically the same in every other way though (in my experience anyway).

You run Integration tests generally before you push code to a "Staging" area (ideally, as part of your build process). This is because Integration tests generally take a lot longer to run (they are actually connecting to external resources), whereas Unit Tests are meant to be run however many times you want.. whenever you want .. and they are quick, because they access in-memory resources.